# Why can a capacitor connected to a battery only charge up until the voltage is equal to the battery?

Tags: capacitor

I've tried searching for an explanation that lays out nicely why the charging of a capacitor stops when its voltage is equal to the supply voltage but I cannot find much. I've only seen one question, which is from Quora which phrases it in a way similar to what I am asking.

https://www.quora.com/Why-the-charging-of-a-capacitor-stops-when-the-voltage-across-the-plates-of-a-capacitor-is-equal-to-the-voltage-across-the-terminals-of-the-battery

But I am not really familiar with the analogy used which is a water pump and diaphragm. But the kind of answer I am looking for is why the moving of electrons stops based on the voltage of the battery. I mean I could settle with answers like "they are connected in parallel so their voltages are equal" or "the capacitor only charges based on what the voltage the battery can give" but I would appreciate a more nicely laid out explanation.

Comment: Flip the question around: how would the capacitor charge beyond the supply voltage given?

Comment: Well, "they are connected in parallel so their voltages are equal" pretty much tells the story... There's not a lot more to say. If the capacitor were to somehow be 'more charged', then it would have a higher voltage than the battery, but they're in parallel so their voltages must be equal.

Comment: Add a series resistor; then Ohm's law tells us that a current will flow iff there is a voltage difference across the resistor.

Comment: The chinese call voltage pressure, so think of an air tank and compressor; you can't raise the pressure of the tank higher than the compressor's output, no matter how much pressure the tank can hold. If you put in too much pressure they explode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why that example uses a water pump and diaphragm, seems overly complex to me. A simpler model would be having the battery as a big water tank and the capacitor as a smaller tank. Both infinitely high. They are connected at the bottom with a small tube that represents the wiring. The water level in each is equivalent to the voltage. If they are not equal, water will flow through the tube until they are. As the tube is small, this takes some time. That is resistance.

This goes both ways, because other than size, the tanks are equivalent. It's precisely the absence of something pump-like that makes it so that water cannot go from a lower level to a higher one.

Answer (score 2):

The electrons flow from the negative electrode of the battery to the negative electrode of the capacitor. If the voltage of both electrodes is the same, there is no force driving the electrons and they don't move. Remember that two electrons repel each other. So an electron in the conductor between the battery and the capacitor is repelled from both sides with the same force and therefore does not move.

If the voltage of the capacitor would be higher than that of the battery, the electrons would move back into the battery. So the voltage of the capacitor can't be higher than the voltage of the battery.